# Drupal 7: how to name the node template without node id?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal 7. I want to create a template file for node of page content type. 
I have created a template file with name page--node--node_id as per the drupal 7 and that page also loaded.

But the problem is id will be different in each environment, so can you give me suggestion for http://example.com/members/high-school, what name should i give for that page node? can I give name using url to that file?

I tried with page--members-high-school, page--node--members-high-school but its not loading.

Comment: I got the answer, please refer this link https://drupal.org/node/1071398 for drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

If your content type is "page", name your template `node--page.tpl.php`.

You can also read this very interesting article about template hook suggestion: https://drupal.org/node/1089656